# Conditional Probability Example

Tags: probability-theory

A drawer contains 8 different pairs of socks.   If 6 socks are taken at random and without replacement, compute the probability that there is at least one matching pair among these 6 socks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to mathSE!  It helps if you give some context and tell us what you've tried, why you're stuck, etc. as best you can.  This can make the answers you get more relevant to your individual situation.

Answer (score 6):

It is little known, but socks have individual identities. There are $\binom{16}{6}$ equally likely ways to choose $6$ socks from the $16$.

Now we find the number of ways to choose $6$ socks, so that there is no pair among them. There are $\dbinom{8}{6}$ ways to choose the "types" of sock we will have.  For each choice of $6$ types, there are $2^6$ ways to choose the actual socks. For at each chosen  "type" of sock, we have $2$ choices as to which of the two socks of that type to take.

Thus the probability there is **no pair** is $p=\dfrac{\binom{8}{6}2^6}{\binom{16}{6}}$.

The probability there is at least one pair is therefore $1-p$.

Answer (score 2):

Select your first sock.  Now you have 15 choices left for your 2nd sock, and 14 of them will allow you to avoid getting a pair.

For your 3rd sock, you have a total of 14 choices remaining, and you can choose any sock other than the first two chosen and their mates to avoid a pair, so you have 12 choices to do this.

Continuing in this manner, we get $\frac{14}{15}\cdot\frac{12}{14}\cdot\frac{10}{13}\cdot\frac{8}{12}\cdot\frac{6}{11}$ for the probability of not getting a matching pair,  so $$1-\frac{14}{15}\cdot\frac{12}{14}\cdot\frac{10}{13}\cdot\frac{8}{12}\cdot\frac{6}{11}$$ gives the probability of getting at least one pair.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- In how many ways can you pull 6 socks out, one at a time, so that there are **no** matching pairs among them?  (How many choices do you have for the first sock?  The second?  The third?)
- In how many ways total can you pull 6 socks out, one at a time?
- What does this mean about the probability that there **is** a matching pair?